# Fetching data from other Spreadsheet by comparing some values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a sample Spreadsheet such as

[image: this]

And I want to import data from this spreadsheet to another spreadsheet, but after comparing some data, such as

[image: this]

**My noob formula for the selected cell `name` in the second image:**

```
=Query(ImportRange("URL of first spreadsheet","sheet!B:D"),"Select Col2 where Col2=A.....(what to add here? this column 'A' is not working for comparing the names)
```

**My Approach:**

I will compare the values from the import range with the existing column i.e. previousSpreadsheet.name.A=thisSpreadsheet.this_name.A and compare every name and `SELECT` values accordingly for the next three columns (in yellow). I hope I'm clear.

What should I add here? Is my approach right? If not, What are the alternatives to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

*(following OP's [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174712/fetching-data-from-other-spreadsheet-by-comparing-some-values#comment111716169_63174969))*

> Also, can I compare two cols with one? such as where `LOWER(Col2)='"&LOWER(A2)&"' or '"&F2&"'`   or `Col2=A2 || F2` something like this? for comparing two cols with one?

If you start using more than one names as *variables*, you may want to consider using other alternatives for the [`where clause`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where), like `matches`

```
=Query(ImportRange("URL of first spreadsheet","sheet!B:D"),
"Select Col2 where Lower(Col2) matches'"&LOWER({A2&"|"&F2})&"'")
```

---

Original answer

Please use

```
=Query(ImportRange("URL of first spreadsheet","sheet!B:D"),"Select Col2 where Col2='"&A2&"'")
```

*(where `A2` is the name you need)*

Pay notice to the syntax referring the cell: single quotes `'` double quotes`"` ampersand `&` cell `A2` and again `&"'`.
***No spaces in between***

Comment: The query is bringing the first name (this) of the previous spreadsheet and the required matched value is printed on the second col. Why so? i.e. ```[row1: "this", row2: "A"]```. Shouldn't this get 'A' only?

Comment: nevermind the header thing was causing issue. Thanks.

Comment: You figured it out. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: One more thing. Can I make this, ```not case-sensitive```? i.e. Can I compare 'a' with 'A' and get 'a' as the output?

Comment: *"Can I make this, not case-sensitive?"*. Just use combinations of the `LOWER` or `UPPER` functions wherever needed as well. e.g. `=Query(ImportRange("URL of first spreadsheet","sheet!B:D"),"Select Col2 where LOWER(Col2)='"&LOWER(A2)&"'")`

Comment: Also, can I compare two cols with one? such as ```where LOWER(Col2)='"&LOWER(A2)&"' or '"&F2&"'  ```  or ```Col2=A2 || F2 ``` something like this? for comparing two cols with one?

Comment: Sure you can. Try something like: `where Lower(Col2)='"&LOWER(A2)&"' or Lower(Col2)='"&LOWER(F2)&"'"` You can also read more about the [query function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("ID", "sheet!B:D"), {1,2,3}, 0)))
```